# call react function inside anonymous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function inside a react component like this

```
addItem: function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    var oldMessages = this.state.messages;
    oldMessages.push({id: data.uid, content: data});

    this.setState({messages: oldMessages});
    this.scrollAndSetTimestamps()
    this.updateCount()
  },
componentDidMount: function() {
this.loadLatestMessages();
var socket = new SockJS('http://127.0.0.1:8080/stomp');
var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
  // subscribe to the /room.uid endpoint
  stompClient.subscribe("/room.1247016", function(data) {
      var message = data.body;
      console.log("Received: "+message);
      this.addItem();
  });
 });
},
```

turns out that the `addItem` is not found when a message arrives. How can I call a react method inside an anon function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest solution is to store correct reference to `this` context in some variable:

```
var self = this;
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
    stompClient.subscribe("/room.1247016", function(data) {
        var message = data.body;
        self.addItem();
    });
});
```

You could also use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), but this is not very readable:

```
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
    stompClient.subscribe("/room.1247016", function(data) {
        var message = data.body;
        this.addItem();
    }.bind(this));
}.bind(this));
```

Finally, you could also go with ES2015 [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which hold lexical scope:

```
stompClient.connect({}, frame => {
    stompClient.subscribe("/room.1247016", data => {
        var message = data.body;
        this.addItem();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I can not test your code truly,
but I think it is because the js scope.
where you call addItem, "this" is no longer point to the component,but the object which calls it.
so, it you want to fix it, a reference method is relieve scope, 
the code like this:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
var _self = this;
_self.loadLatestMessages();
var socket = new SockJS('http://127.0.0.1:8080/stomp');
var stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
  // subscribe to the /room.uid endpoint
  stompClient.subscribe("/room.1247016", function(data) {
      var message = data.body;
      console.log("Received: "+message);
      _self.addItem();
  });
 });
},
```